# Fetch table value using Accessor In Laravel 8 for image

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

My model name is 'data' and the field name is 'image'.

In the Model when I try to fetch the URL of the image it shows this error `Undefined property: App\Models\Data::$image` using `$this->image;`.

But when I try to fetch name using `$this->name` It's working fine.

I also attached the screenshot of DB for better understanding.

[image]

*Note:* I add `use Storage;` In the model.

Please help me for solving the issue.

**Controller**

[image]

**Model**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer Reference
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```
public function getImageAttribute($image)
{
    $Img_Url = $image;
    return $ImgUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before starting to learn querying in laravel, tidy up your code and adjust it to the standard syntax first so you don't make it difficult for yourself.

accept model data in a variable

for example i get latest row

```
$mydata = \App\Models\Data::orderBy('id','DESC')->first();
```

if you want to get your data, you can do this

```
$mydata->name;
$mydata->image;
```

if still not working, please add a screenshot of your model.

[comment answer]

```
public function getImageAttribute ($id) {
     return Data::where('id',$id)->first()->image;
}
```

Comment: Hi AR thank you for your response, please check this screenshot https://ibb.co/mFVmjLW

Comment: @DevWebTK you need to get the data by query first, in your model there is also no constructor, which if you have a lot of data, with your current code will not work

i have updated my code on answer section.

Comment: I write the constructor as well in the controller, please have a look at https://ibb.co/VD07S53

Comment: Error page - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/21686111?key=0e01c4ca6102f090809a3d9f87d20205 @aditya